# my data won't reach my function on component.ts (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase of google and I'm trying to connect the login page with the registered accounts but when I send the inputs from the html page to the component.ts it won't read the data or reach to the firebase 
but when I try it with initialize it to var's it worked

components.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      //email:string = 'email@yahoo.fr'; 
      //password:string = 'password'; // it connect when i initialize the var's

      constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router:Router) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      seConnecter(email,password)
      {
        this.authService.signInUser(email,password).then(
          () => {
            alert('Welcome '+ email);
            this.router.navigate(['']);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log('Connection Problem '+error);
            alert('Account inaccessible');
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>
        log-In
    </h1>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">E-mail :</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" required id="email" #email>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="alterEgo">Password :</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" required id="password" #password>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)='seConnecter(email,password)'>Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending your elements to your method(**seConnecter**) . modify your html like the following:

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)='seConnecter(email.value,password.value)'>Submit</button>
```

**Edit** :

define a model :

```
export interface LoginModel {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

your html :

```
<form (submit)="seConnecter($event)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">E-mail :</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" required #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="this.model.email" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="alterEgo">Password :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="this.model.password" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

typescript:

```
  seConnecter(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.authService.signInUser(this.model.email, this.model.password).then(
      () => {
        alert('Welcome ' + this.model.email);
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Connection Problem ' + error);
        alert('Account inaccessible');
      }
    );
  }
```

another way , based on your question is, modify the type of your button element to button instead of submit :

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">E-mail :</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" required id="email" #email>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="alterEgo">Password :</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" required id="password" #password>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)='seConnecter(email.value,password.value)'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

typescript :

```
  seConnecter(email: string,password: string)
  { 
     ...
  }
```

Comment: even when i write it like that it is the same

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `seConnecter()`is missing the correct parameters:

This should work:

```
 seConnecter(email, password)
 {
 this.authService.signInUser(email,password).then(
  () => {
    alert('Welcome '+ email);
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  },
    (error) => {
       console.log('Connection Problem '+error);
       alert('Account inaccessible');
      }
    );
 }
```

Comment: sorry i forget to add it when i post the question but even with the parameters it won't work

Comment: Actually you only need to put email.value and password.value in place as two way binding it overengineerd at this place.

Comment: the same problem it doesn't reach to the function on component.ts

Comment: could you try to remove `type="submit"` on the button?

Comment: Oh Wow :( 
`type="button"` my next educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

if you choses template form you can get the form value without create any property at the component level I think this what all template form all about otherwise we use reactive form

*template*

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>
        log-In
    </h1>
    <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="seConnecter(loginForm.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">E-mail :</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" required id="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="alterEgo">Password :</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" required id="password" >
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

> form form control you need to put ngModel directive and set the name

you can disable the submit button until the form is valid base of the validation setup

```html
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="loginForm?.form.invalid" >
     Submit
 </button>
```

*component*

```js
  seConnecter(formValue) {
    const {email , password} = formValue;
    ....
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-huxapo)